# how to make delay on discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've successfully made a ping command, calculating my bot's ping. But I want it to have a delay, about 2 seconds before it sends it result.

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "shows the bot/'s ping",
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('`ping is being calculated...`').then(msg => {
            const ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
            msg.channel.send('`bot\'s` ping: ' + ping + "`ms`")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) ?

Answer (score 3):

Using setTimeout(() => {code}, timeMs) achieves exactly that;

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: "shows the bot/'s ping",
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('`ping is being calculated...`').then(msg => {
           setTimeout(() => {
            const ping = msg.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp;
            msg.channel.send('`bot\'s` ping: ' + ping + "`ms`")
            }, 2000)
        })
    }
}
```